# How to put multiple breaks in cut function in R?

Tags: r, function, multiple-columns, cut

I have 3 columns that I want to put labels depending in 3 differents breaks for each column like in the example but I don't know how because I can label multiple columns for the same break but not for differents breaks (br1, br2, br3).

```
var <- 1:10

x1 <- rnorm(10, mean=100, sd=25)
x2 <- rnorm(10, mean=100, sd=25)
x3 <- rnorm(10, mean=100, sd=25)
df <- data.frame(var,x1,x2,x3)

#With 1 break for all the columns
br1 <-c(50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140)
df2 <-data.frame(lapply(df[, 2:4], cut, br=br1, labels=c(1:9)))
```

The problem: how can I use the following breaks(#breaks 2 and 3) for column x2 and x3 in the same code or any idea so each column(x1, x2, x3) have a break (br1, br2, br3)?

```
#breaks 2 and 3
br2 <-c(30,40,45,55,61,70,98,105,115,138)
br3<-c(20,25,30,35,38,42,45,70,95,132)
```

Comment: Is my answer somehow helpful?

Comment: @slava-kohut your answer helped me, now its easy to continue my work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: consider upvoting or accepting then

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map`:

```
Map(function(x, y, labels=1:9) cut(x, y, labels = labels), df[, 2:4], list(br1, br2, br3))
```

The output is a list of columns of `df`. It can be converted to a data frame using `as.data.frame`. You can also add other parameters to `cut` (e.g., `include_lowest`). Values outside of the intervals provided are `NA`s.

```
# OUTPUT
$x1
 [1] 6    8    <NA> 8    9    4    5    <NA> 6    8   
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

$x2
 [1] 8 6 6 5 3 7 8 6 9 8
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

$x3
 [1] 8    9    <NA> 9    9    9    <NA> 9    8    8   
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)
var <- 1:10

x1 <- rnorm(10, mean=100, sd=25)
x2 <- rnorm(10, mean=100, sd=25)
x3 <- rnorm(10, mean=100, sd=25)
df <- data.frame(var,x1,x2,x3)

#With 1 break for all the columns
br1 <-c(50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140)
br2 <-c(30,40,45,55,61,70,98,105,115,138)
br3<-c(20,25,30,35,38,42,45,70,95,132)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning `cut` values as new columns with a `for` loop using `get()` to use name of variable in column suffix:

```
set.seed(1082019)
#...

for(b in c("br1", "br2", "br3")) 
    df[paste0(names(df)[2:4], "_", b)] <- lapply(df[, 2:4], cut, br=get(b), labels=c(1:9))

df

#    var        x1        x2        x3 x1_br1 x2_br1 x3_br1 x1_br2 x2_br2 x3_br2 x1_br3 x2_br3 x3_br3
# 1    1 121.95508  98.40327 139.31413      8      5      9      9      7   <NA>      9      9   <NA>
# 2    2 105.28775 116.99844  83.12366      6      7      4      8      9      6      9      9      8
# 3    3  80.17226 118.92694 104.57693      4      7      6      6      9      7      8      9      9
# 4    4 146.94335  90.50056  58.35752   <NA>      5      1   <NA>      6      4   <NA>      8      7
# 5    5  98.15953  23.58072  86.67441      5   <NA>      4      7   <NA>      6      9      1      8
# 6    6 137.52613  74.83507  95.49531      9      3      5      9      6      6   <NA>      8      9
# 7    7  51.41213 141.01571  68.36462      1   <NA>      2      3   <NA>      5      7   <NA>      7
# 8    8  74.05926 134.66125  93.40060      3      9      5      6      9      6      8   <NA>      8
# 9    9  63.16221  52.25081  76.96090      2      1      3      5      3      6      7      7      8
# 10  10 123.96491  73.03856 138.41414      8      3      9      9      6   <NA>      9      8   <NA>
```